# Convert column in data.frame to date

Tags: r, date, dplyr, magrittr

My dataframe

```
a1 <- c("a","a","b","b","c","d","e","e")
b2 <- c("01.01.2015", "02.02.2015", "14.02.2012", "16.08.2008", "17.06.2003", "31.01.2015", "07.01.2022", "09.05.2001")
c3 <- c("1a", "2b", "3c", "4d", "5e", "6f", "7g", "8h")
d3 <- c(1:8)

df2 <- data.frame(a1,b2,c3,d3, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

My code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

test <- df2 %>%
    group_by(a1) %>% 
    as.Date(b2, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

> Error in as.Date.default(., b2, format = "%d.%m.%Y") : 
>     do not know how to convert '.' to class “Date”

Well, I tried without the pipe:

```
df$b2 <- as.Date(df$b2, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

> Error in df$b2 : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

First: Why do I get two different error messages since I am (for my understanding) am doing the same?

Second, why cant I convert my column to date?!

I might should add that I am aware of using `mutate` to alter the column as `date` format. But I wonder why my approach is not working.

Comment: a remark for your "First": you seem to have no data.frame called `df` but one called `df2`

Comment: `df` is a function. You probably mean `df2`. So, the answer to your question is: typo.

Comment: @Pascal yes, to question one.

Comment: And to question 2. `df2$b2 <- as.Date(df2$b2, format = "%d.%m.%Y")` works.

Comment: @Pascal yes, but not when I pipe it.

Comment: I don't know, I never use this strange syntax `%>%`.

Comment: Part of your issue is that df is a reserved word. ": object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do the transformations within `mutate`

```
df2 %>%
   group_by(a1) %>%
   mutate(b2=as.Date(b2, format = "%d.%m.%Y"))
#    a1         b2    c3    d3
#  (chr)     (date) (chr) (int)
#1     a 2015-01-01    1a     1
#2     a 2015-02-02    2b     2
#3     b 2012-02-14    3c     3
#4     b 2008-08-16    4d     4
#5     c 2003-06-17    5e     5
#6     d 2015-01-31    6f     6
#7     e 2022-01-07    7g     7
#8     e 2001-05-09    8h     8
```

If we need to do only the transformation, we don't need to group by 'a1'.

```
mutate(df2, b2= as.Date(b2, format= "%d.%m.%Y"))
```

By using `%<>%` operator from `magrittr`, we can transform in place.

```
df2 %<>%
  mutate(b2= as.Date(b2, format= "%d.%m.%Y"))
```

Comment: That works, yes. However, I do not understand why my approach is not working?!

Comment: @Chrissl In the `dplyr` framework, we use either `mutate/transmute` to change/create a new column or `summarise` to get a summary output per group.

Comment: ok. What is the particular advantage in using the dplyr package here. It is more typing, and does the same?!

Comment: @Chrissl For this case, you don't need the `group_by` step, I am just trying to use your code to show where you went wrong.

Comment: @Chrissl Regarding the advantage part, some people say that it is easier to read when using `%>%`.  There might be some truth behind that because when I showed the dplyr code and some other code that gives the same result to a python guy (with no experience with R), he could understand it better with dplyr.  For me, it is subjective.

Comment: Ah. When I wnat to change the format of a column (i.e. `chr` to date) I have to use a combination of `%>%` and `%<>%` when keep on piping stuff. Like `test <- df2 %>%
  group_by(a1) %<%>%
  mutate(b2 == as.Date(b2, format = "%d.%m.%Y") %>% do more %>% do more %>% do more...`

Comment: @Chrissl You don't need to use `%<>%`.  You can assign it to the same object or a new object i.e. `test <- df2 %>% group_by(a1) %>% mutate(b2= as.Date(b2, format='%d.%m.%Y'))`

Comment: akrun, thanks for sticking with me. Then I still do not understand why `test <- df2 %>%
    group_by(a1) %>% 
    as.Date(b2, format = "%d.%m.%Y")` is not working.... It should be the same as `df2 %>%
   group_by(a1) %>%
   mutate(b2=as.Date(b2, format = "%d.%m.%Y"))`

Comment: @Chrissl What I meant is that without using `test <- ` or `df2 <-`, you can update the `df2` by using the `%<>%` operator.