# R: Converting timestamp to date

Tags: mongodb, timestamp

I have a timestamp pulled from MongoDB

example: `2007-01-01 01:00:00`

I need it to be a simple date: `2007-01-01`

Been looking at: [Convert UNIX epoch to Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456241/convert-unix-epoch-to-date-object)

Having a hard time formatting

Comment: Are these the real (string) values? If yes, simply use `{ $substrCP: [ <timestamp>, 0, 10 ] }`

Answer (score 0):

Using sources:
[Convert column in data.frame to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33408636/convert-column-in-data-frame-to-date)

I had to assess if the class that I was trying to convert was a class that `as.Date` was able to take.

Turns out it was a `data.frame` class

Used the following to convert it:

```
dat_dump %>%
            mutate( date = as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```