# converting chr (mm/dd/yyyy) to date with lubridate in r

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a column called date, chr class, format mm/dd/yyyy.

I have tried converting it to date with lubridate as follows:

```
df$date<- df %>% as.Date(date) 
df$date<- df %>% as_date(date)
```

both resulted in the Error in as.Date.default(., date): do not know how to convert '.' to class “Date”

```
df$date<- df %>% mdy(date)
```

resulted in Error in as.character(x): cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: Try base R: `df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: Or  with lubridate: `lubridate::mdy(df$date)`

Comment: Instead of `df$date<- df %>% mdy(date)`  try  `df <- df %>% mutate(date = mdy(date))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33408671/10276092 - The error means you are trying to write a dataframe into a column. Another option is to skip the pipe `df$date<-as.Date(df$date)`

Comment: including the format with as.Date results in Error in data$date: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Please provide a sample of  `df` paste the output of `dput(df)` into the question to make the question reproducible.

Comment: @LillianWelsh, start form a clean state, i.e import your dataset again as your current `df$date` seems to be corrupt from previous attempts.

Comment: df<- df %>% mutate(date= mdy(date)) results in Error in UseMethod("mutate"): no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: how do I provide a sample?

Answer (score 0):

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

should do it.